# Align form items using Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a mobile login page using bootstrap 5 and a custom css. However, I cannot align the form items inside the form. How could I do this?

```css
.row {
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* border: solid 3px black; */
}

.card {
  height: 380px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  /* border: solid 3px green; */
}

.card-body {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  /* border: solid 3px red; */
}

.form-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* border: solid 3px blue; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/custom.css">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form-content">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="userEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userPass" class="form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPass">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    .row {
      height: 100vh;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      /* border: solid 3px black; */
    }
    
    .card {
      height: 380px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: aliceblue;
      /* border: solid 3px green; */
    }
    
    .card-body {
      height: 80%;
      width: 100%;
      /* border: solid 3px red; */
    }
    
    .form-content {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      /* border: solid 3px blue; */
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I appreciate any help!!

Comment: it depends on what you mean by align, but you don't need to use class "form-group" in bootstrap 5 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to align it ?

If you want to align it in the center, use those properties applied your form tag in css:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

or in bootstrap add in the form classes :

```html
<form class="d-flex-col justify-content-center align-items-center">
```

Comment: Perfect, that's really how I wanted to align the elements in the form. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `mt-2` with your second and third `form-group` classes. This will had a half `rem` of margin for each specified area.

```css
.row {
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* border: solid 3px black; */
}

.card {
  height: 380px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  /* border: solid 3px green; */
}

.card-body {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  /* border: solid 3px red; */
}

.form-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* border: solid 3px blue; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/custom.css">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form-content">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="userEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mt-2">
                <label for="userPass" class="form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPass">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mt-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    .row {
      height: 100vh;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      /* border: solid 3px black; */
    }
    
    .card {
      height: 380px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: aliceblue;
      /* border: solid 3px green; */
    }
    
    .card-body {
      height: 80%;
      width: 100%;
      /* border: solid 3px red; */
    }
    
    .form-content {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      /* border: solid 3px blue; */
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```